# cs50 credit.c stops working when reading input from a function, pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, cs50

I've been teaching myself some C and did the problems from the cs50 course. My program works fine but I tried to make it simpler and divide it in as many functions as possible. Everything worked except the *readInput* function. I'm pretty sure it has to do with how the pointer from the array works and I have tried to do something someone suggested here on SO but I get a segmentation fault, I have tried different ways to do this but everything leads to more faults. Any tips would be highly appreciated!

```
void readInput(int **digits){
    char c; // char to get the digits
    int position = 0; // pos in the array
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') { 
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') { 
        (*digits)[position] = c - '0'; 
        position++;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("Please enter your credit card number\n");
    int digits[16];
    intitializeArray(16, digits);
    readInput(&digits);
    int length = getLength(digits);
    int resultSecondDigits = getValueSecondDigits(length, digits);
    int resultFirstDigits = getValueFirstDigits(length, digits);
    checkValidity(resultFirstDigits+resultSecondDigits, digits);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Too many stars. Try `int readInput(int *digits)` and `digits[position] = c - '0';` and call it like `readInput(digits);`. The function should return `int` the number of digits read, instead of fumbling with `int length = getLength(digits);` Aside, `char c` should be `int c` to match the return value from `getchar()`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! This kinda confuses me since I thought I have to pass pointers to change the values in the array but I'll look further into it!

Comment: So, `int length = readInput(digits);`. The function receives a pointer which you can index directly, because the array passed "decays" to a pointer to its first element.

Answer (score 1):

Read the compiler warnings properly it says

> pembroke11.c:2:6: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int
>   (*)[16]’  void readInput(int **digits){

It should be like this

```
void readInput(int (*digits)[16]){ 
/* some code */
}
```

OR

No need to pass address of `digits` to `readInput()` function, just pass pass the array name.

```
void readInput(int *digits){
        int c; // char to get the digits
        int position = 0; // pos in the array
        while ((c = getchar()) !='\n') { /* type of c should be int as getchar() returns int */
                if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                        digits[position] = c - '0';
                        printf("%d\n", digits[position]);
                        position++;
                }
        }
}
```